# Cannot access config() in ServiceProvider | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I created a custom service provider for paypal.
When I try to access config from inside the provider, it returns null.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(ApiContext::class, function($app){
        $paypalConf = $app['config']->get('paypal');
        $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $paypalConf['client_id'],$paypalConf['client_secret']
        )); 
        $apiContext->setConfig($paypalConf['settings']);
        return $apiContext;
    });
}
```

But it throws following error

```
if (empty($credObj)) {
        throw new PayPalInvalidCredentialException("Credential not found for " .  ($userId ? $userId : " default user") .
        ". Please make sure your configuration/APIContext has credential information");
    }
```

> "Credential not found for  default user. Please make sure your configuration/APIContext has credential information

Which is certainly because my config file is returning null.

Here is my **paypal.php**

```
return [
'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID', ''),
'client_secret' => env('PAYPAL_SECRET', ''),
'settings' => [
    'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', ''),
    'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
    'log.LogEnabled' => true,
    'log.FileName' => storage_path().'/logs/paypal.log',
    'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'
]];
```

and the PAYPAL credentials exists in .env file.

I have tried clearing the config and caching it again, but it didn't work.

## ***Update***

Seems like the ***register*** method isn't working in the service provider.
But I have registered the provider in config/app.php

Comment: Have you tried `dd($paypalConf, $app['config']->get('app.name'))`, in the service provider after first line? I smell a typo kind of error.

Comment: @Kyslik dd isn't working there.

Comment: Have you registered the service provider in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @Kyslik yes the provider is registered in the providers array.

Comment: Then dd out of the closure, you need to know if the register method is executing.

Comment: @Kyslik seems like the register method isn't executing!. What todo ?, And yes I have registered the provider. :(

Comment: Did you use artisan command to create the provider? Did you `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Kyslik yes, I autoloaded the files again via ***composer dump-autoload***.

Comment: Now try `composer dump-autoload -o` (optimize) and if that works you simply have a typo, or wrong namespace. As I said in the first comment I smell typo kind of error.

Comment: @Kyslik I am afraid it isn't a typo. I have tried optimize flag too.

Comment: What Laravel version is this?

Comment: Laravel v5.6, PHP7.2

Answer (score 4):

Without more information ...

clear the config cache: `php artisan config:clear`

If you have a cached config and you add anything to the config files or env, including another service provider to `config/app.php`, it won't get picked up because its using a cached version of your config.

You can verify this kind of stuff just by going into `tinker` and requesting these config values after making changes to any config files or env.

Comment: I have already cleared the cached config. It still didn't work. I removed the service provider and went with manual class instantiation. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the config folder `paypal.php` not `paypal.config` :

```
<?php

    return [
        'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID', ''),
        'client_secret' => env('PAYPAL_SECRET', ''),
        'settings' => [
            'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', ''),
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path().'/logs/paypal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'
    ]];
```

Then you can get the values :

```
Config::get('paypal.client_id');
Config::get('paypal.settings.mode');
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, it's config/paypal.php

Comment: Did you created the file in the config folder ? and did you use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` at the top of the service provider ?

Comment: the config folder that comes with laravel folder my paypal.php resides in that folder. and yes I am using Config; ***use Config***

Comment: try the helper method `config('paypal.client_id');` !

Comment: nope, I was trying the helper first, then shifted to app['config'] and even the Facade. None of them worked. I am literally pulling hair rn.